# Error 'System.IO.MemoryStream Microsoft.IO.RecyblableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream()' - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, epplus

hasta hace poco estaba trabajando muy bien con una clase que me ayuda a exportar a excel lo que tengan mis datagridview, pero despues de revisar las bibliotecas que uso (Epplus) para hacer uso de los archivos de excel, me percate que se necesitaba actualizar la version, anteriormente tenia la 7.0.2 y pues la actualice a la mas reciente que es la 7.0.4, pero esta biblioteca(Epplus) ocupa de otra llamada Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream la cual tambien necesitaba de una actualizacion, esta ultima biblioteca la tenia en la v. 2.3.2 y la actualice a la mas reciente la cual es la 3.0.0.
Al realizar estas actualizaciones y volver a trabajar con mi aplicacion y querer exportar la info de mi dgv a excel me aparecio este error:

> Error importing file: method not found: 'System.IO.MemoryStream
> Microsoft.IO.RecyblableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream()'

Lo que se me hizo raro ya que estaba funcionando perfectamente, por lo que me gustaria que me apoyaran a decirme o compartir posibles soluciones a esto, por ahora solo volvi a cambiar las versiones a las que tenia anteriormente pero me gustaria saber como solucionar esto.
Les comparto mi codigo para exportar la info de los dgv a excel:

```
public void ExportarAExcel(DataGridView dataGridView)
        {
            try
            {
                // Crear un nuevo archivo de Excel
                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    // Crear una nueva hoja de trabajo en el archivo de Excel
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Detalle");

                    // Obtener los datos del DataGridView
                    DataTable dataTable = GetDataTableFromDataGridView(dataGridView);

                    // Establecer el estilo de los encabezados de columna
                    using (ExcelRange headerRange = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, dataTable.Columns.Count])
                    {
                        headerRange.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    }

                    // Escribir los encabezados de columna en la hoja de trabajo
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    }

                    // Escribir los datos en la hoja de trabajo
                    for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 0; col < dataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 1].Value = dataTable.Rows[row][col];
                        }
                    }

                    // Ajustar el ancho de las columnas al contenido
                    worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

                    // Guardar el archivo de Excel en la ruta seleccionada por el usuario
                    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Archivos de Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
                    saveFileDialog.Title = "Save Excel File";
                    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

                    if (saveFileDialog.FileName != "")
                    {
                        FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                        excelPackage.SaveAs(excelFile);
                        MessageBox.Show("The data has been successfully exported to Excel", "Successful Export", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                        // Abrir el documento de Excel
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(excelFile.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Mostrar un mensaje de error en caso de falla durante la exportación
                MessageBox.Show($"Error exporting data to Excel: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

private DataTable GetDataTableFromDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            // Crear las columnas en el DataTable
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText);
            }

            // Agregar las filas al DataTable
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataRow[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

Espero puesdan ayudarme por favor, cualquier cosa que sepan estaria muy agradecido que me la compartieran.

**Estoy trabajando con un proyecto de Windows Forms con tarjet framework 4.8**

Comment: Revisa si las dependencias están correctas o tienen observaciones (si tienen íconos de advertencia amarillos)

Comment: Al parecer no, las revise pero no tienen ningun signo de error,/advertencia. Esta como normalmente deberia de estar.

Comment: Puedes probar dando **clean** y **build**, o directamente **rebuild**; si no funciona revisa la compatibilidad con framework 4.8 de la versión de la librería que actualizaste; en NetCore la compatibilidad de versiones es evidente, pero lamentablemente en framework no

Comment: Ya encontre el Error, al parecer EPPlus 7 no es compatible con la version 3.0.0 de la biblioteca Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream version 3.0.0 que es la mas reciente. Aqui encontre la respuesta: https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/issues/1215